# How to access the current cordinate of UIButton from the super view, when occur the UIGestureRecognizerStateEnd

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

I am new to iOS development. Now I am implementing an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` model application. I have one `UIButton` for `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. My question is, how can access the reside coordinate of `UIButton` from the super view (such as `UIView`, `UIScrollView` etc?)

if anybody know please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
CGRect rectInSuperView = [button convertRect:button.frame toView:superview];
```

Check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertRect%3atoView%3a)

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I can not get the exact coordinate of UIButton.In my case the UIButton coordinate is (109,176,72,37) but the convertRect:toView: return value is (218,352,72,37),what is the reason for value change?

Comment: I got it, change the code to CGRect rectInSuperView = [[button superview] convertRect:button.frame toView:Yourview];